# Correct way of aligning baseline in tikz picture captions

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I made a picture using tikz, and I would like to correctly align the captions. This is what I did:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\pgfmathparse{sqrt(12)}
\coordinate (C) at (-2,\pgfmathresult);
\coordinate (A) at (-4,0);
\coordinate (B) at (4,0);
\coordinate (H) at (-2,0);
\draw[color=blue, line width=2pt] (A) -- (H);

\draw [fill=blue] (A) circle (2.0pt);
\draw[anchor=north] (A) node {$A$};

\draw [fill=blue] (B) circle (2.0pt);
\draw[anchor=north] (B) node {$B$};

\draw [fill=blue] (H) circle (2.0pt);
\draw[anchor=north] (H) node {$H$};

\draw [fill=blue] (C) circle (2.0pt);
\draw[anchor=south] (C) node {$C$};

\draw[anchor=north] (-3,0) node {$1$};
\draw[anchor=north] (1,0) node {$x$};
\draw[anchor=west] (-2,\pgfmathresult/2) node {$\sqrt{x}$};

\draw[color=blue, line width=2pt] (H) -- (B);
\draw[color=blue, line width=2pt] (B) arc (0:180:4);
\draw[color=red, line width=2pt] (H) -- (C);
\draw[color=purple, line width=2pt] (A) -- (C) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And this is the output:

[image]

As you can see, *H*, *B* and *x* are not properly aligned: *x* is misplaced.

Which is the correct way to align them?

Comment: `A`, `1`, `H, `x` and `B` aren't captions but node and edge labels :-). for start for `x` try to write `x\vphantom{X}`.

Comment: Use `text height=...` and `text deph=...` as node options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i suppose that you like like this:

[image]

i took a liberty and with use of the library `quotes` make your code quite shorter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    line cap=round,
    auto=right,
    label distance=0.5ex,
    dot/.style={circle,fill=blue,inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0pt},
every edge quotes/.append style={text=black, text height=2ex}
                        ]
\pgfmathparse{sqrt(12)}
\coordinate[label=$C$]       (C) at (-2,\pgfmathresult);
\coordinate[label=below:$A$] (A) at (-4,0);
\coordinate[label=below:$B$] (B) at ( 4,0);
\coordinate[label=below:$H$] (H) at (-2,0);
%
\foreach \i in {A, B, C, H}
\node[dot] at (\i) {};
    \begin{scope}[line width=2pt]
\draw[color=blue]   (A) to ["1"] (H)
                        to ["$x$"] (B) arc(0:180:4);
\draw[color=red]    (H) to ["$\sqrt{x}$"] (C);
\draw[color=purple] (A) -- (C) -- (B);
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, this code is very elegant. Where exactly did you solve my problem? It is just the line "label distance=0.5ex"?

Comment: with `every edge quotes/.append style={text=black, text height=2ex}` where `text height=2ex` reserve space for text in edge quote (label). with `label distance=0.5ex` are defined distance of  coordinates labels so, that they are aligned with edges.